# Lxpanel plugin and threads

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk

I'm writing a multithreaded Lxpanel plugin (using C and GTK2) and I'm trying to change GUI (for example, add and remove widget) in separate thread, but it doesn't work - when I'm trying to add a label there is an empty space.

```
//includes

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *l1;
    GtkWidget *l2;
} Plug;

/*thread function*/
gboolean test_func(Plugin *plugin){
    Plug *priv=plugin->priv;
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(plugin->pwid), priv->l1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(plugin->pwid), priv->l2);
    return FALSE;
}
/*called when plugin is added*/
static int test_constructor(Plugin *plugin, char **fp){
    Plug *priv=g_new0(Plug, 1);
    plugin->pwid=gtk_event_box_new();
    plugin->priv=priv;
    priv->l1=gtk_label_new("l1");
    priv->l2=gtk_label_new("l2");
    g_thread_new(
        "test_thread", (GThreadFunc)test_func, plugin
    );
    //g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)test_func, plugin);
    //test_func(plugin);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(plugin->pwid), priv->l1);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(plugin->pwid, 30, 25);
    gtk_widget_set_has_window(plugin->pwid, FALSE);
    gtk_widget_show_all(plugin->pwid);
    return 1;
}
/*called when plugin is removed*/
static void test_destructor(Plugin *plugin){
    Plug *priv=plugin->priv;
    gtk_widget_destroy(priv->l1);
    gtk_widget_destroy(priv->l2);
    g_free(priv);
}
/*settings*/
PluginClass test_plugin_class = {

    PLUGINCLASS_VERSIONING,

    type : "test",
    name : N_("test"),
    version: "1.0",
    description : N_("test"),

    one_per_system : TRUE,

    expand_available : FALSE,

    constructor : test_constructor,
    destructor  : test_destructor,
    config : NULL,
    save : NULL
};
```

I've also tried g_idle_add - it doesn't work either. And when I add gdk_threads_enter() and gdk_threads__leave() in the `test_func` function lxpanel simply hangs. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multiple threads with GTK+ is usually a design mistake, and often difficult to get correct: I suggest you try to modify your code to fit the event loop driven model (e.g. with g_idle_add).

As to why the widgets are invisible: you call gtk_widget_show_all() before l2 is added to the container. Which means you need to explicitly set l2 visible at some point (you can do it before adding it to a container, e.g. at creation time).

Comment: Thank you, if I add `gtk_widget_show(priv->l2);` before `gtk_container_add`, the label is displayed correctly. However, when I add and then remove labels (remove l1, show l2, add l2, remove l2, add l2, show l2) there is still an empty space. By the way, I mentioned that I've tried to use g_idle_add, and it didn't work. Moreover, I need a separate thread to perform some file operations at the background, so I can't get rid of threads.

Comment: Sure, using threads for other things may be needed: I was just saying that calling gtk functions from several threads is typically a very bad idea. Also, g_idle_add() is a widely used function: it's unlikely that it would be somehow broken.

Comment: With regards to removing and re-adding widgets: are you aware that Container will steal the reference when you do _add() and then _remove()? In other words when you remove a widget, it automatically gets destroyed unless you have taken another reference (this also means your custom destroy function probably shouldn't call destroy on the labels)

Comment: I mean it didn't work as expected. No, I was unaware of this behavior of _remove, I feel I should read the documentation more carefully.